# What's the connotation of virility?

Tags: connotation

What is the connotation of "virility"?
Is virility usually used in a bad derogatory sense?

Thanks. 
-K

Comment: It has nothing to do with _virus_ or _villain_, if that phonetic similarity might possibly be what made you wonder. Virility comes from an old word for a man; virus, from poison; villain, from house.

Comment: What research have you done before asking here?

Comment: Etymologically, *virility* merely means *manliness* -- what connotations would you think *manliness* has?

Answer (score 3):

The definition given in Oxford Dictionaries Online is:

> (in a man) the quality of having strength, energy and a strong sex
>   drive; manliness

It carries no implication of any negative qualities.

Comment: Indeed. In fact most real men would take it as a compliment.